# How to unlock hyperledger fabric's username?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I tried 10 times enrollment with an invalid password, and then the Fabric CA locked my username. do you know how to unlock the username?

Answer (score 0):

Fabric CA is recording the number of failed attempts which has reached the `passwordattempts` setting.
Looking at the [code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/9b0e156edd9b244254b0ffb5189e6aeaa9f51bea/lib/serverrequestcontext.go#L114) suggests you can either reset the number of attempts to zero in the persistence or change the [passwordattempts](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/c025d5ea5243d74d919df2d442975bd60386c37c/cmd/fabric-ca-server/config.go#L483) setting to 0, which bypasses the test all together.